# My Android application crashes when I change screen orientation

Tags: android

In my application, network access is running in a thread. Whenever I change screen orientation, my application crashes. How might I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the Answers..
I have got solution by Implementing Activity Life cycle method OnStop.
In that method I have just added the below code

```
@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    if(thread!=null)
        thread.stop();
    if(dialog!=null)
        dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The activity actually stops and restarts every time the device orientation changes. You need to write your thread with that in mind, i.e. stopping the thread and restarting it when the device changes orientation, perhaps saving the state in between.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you should go through the Activity Life Cycle first.

Since whenever there is a change in the orientation OnCreate() method is called,

causes crashing of your application.

Best Regards,
~Anup

Comment: hi Anup, I was trying to implement the onRestart() and change orientation, but it wont call this method, it again call the onCreate().

Comment: Hey sorry it basically called onCreate()

Answer (score 1):

you can have your application listen for events that would cause a restart – like orientation and keyboard visibility changes – and handle them within your Activity.

Start by adding the `android:configChanges` node to your Activity's manifest node

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Then within the Activity override the onConfigurationChanged method and call setContentView to force the GUI layout to be re-done in the new orientation.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
}
```

Comment: It wont work dude in my case. the onConfigurationChanged() is not called while changing the orientation. Is there any alternative for that?