# Android application crashes with orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

The application has one main activity and two fragments. The main activity hosts `MainFragment` and `MainFragment` contain a button to commit `BreedingFragment` (run). The application works fine only when the orientation is not changed but crashes when the `BreedingFragment` is open and orientation changes.

After investigating on **stackoverflow** for few hours, I found the following articles and followed the answers but It did not debug the problem.

1. [Android Application Crashes With Orientation Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178807/android-application-crashes-with-orientation-changes)
2. [Orientation change Crash Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806856/orientation-change-crash-application)
3. [Rotation of screen crashes android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787918/rotation-of-screen-crashes-android-app)
4. [My Android application crashes when I change screen orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248273/my-android-application-crashes-when-i-change-screen-orientation)

The answers mainly suggest to use the following code in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

**The last thread suggests the following to consider:**

> The activity actually stops and restarts every time the device
>   orientation changes. You need to write your thread with that in mind,
>   i.e. stopping the thread and restarting it when the device changes
>   orientation, perhaps saving the state in between.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**MainFragment:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        Button breedButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.pokemon_breeding_button);

        breedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, new BreedingFragment());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

**BreedingFragment:**

```
public class BreedingFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_breeding, container, false);
    }
}
```

**Log Cat:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.revittechnology.zapdos, PID: 12795
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.revittechnology.zapdos/com.revittechnology.zapdos.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4014)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:720)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:331)
                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2018)
                      at com.revittechnology.zapdos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4014) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.revittechnology.zapdos.MainFragment did not create a view.
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2319)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:331) 
                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2018) 
                      at com.revittechnology.zapdos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4014) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12795 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "why am I crashing?", use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Yes, if your question is about the cause of the crash that you're observing, then please post the crash stacktrace here.

Comment: You shouldn't have your Fragments replace themselves

Comment: @cricket_007 What do you suggest instead? Thanks

Comment: If you follow this guide, it shows how to "callback" to the activity to replace a Fragment on a click event. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: You have to place the ConfigChanges line into the scope of your activity in Manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Main Activity and Main Fragment.]
The above photo elaborates the case. `MainActivity.java` which hosts `MainFragment.java` and the Main Fragment has one button which launches another fragment.

**What are my requirements?**

1. The Main Activity just hosts the Main Fragment and doesn't have
   anything else.
2. Main Fragment has button to launch second Fragment.
3. Close (end/ finish) the second Fragment when back button is pressed
   (return to Main Activity).
4. Works with device (screen) rotation.

The first step is to create Main Activity. There are few things to **consider** in Main Activity:

1. Extends `MainActivity` to `FragmentActivity`

`public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity` as follows:

2. Check `savedInstanceState` and if it is `null` then run the
   MainFragment. The reason we are doing this to avoid running again
   and again the MainFragment with device rotation.

Here is the code for **`MainActivity.java`**:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentManager fManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
            fTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, new MainFragment());
            fTransaction.commit();
        }

    }
}
```

Make sure to have following lines of code in **`activity_main.xml`**:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.revittechnology.zapdos.MainFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment" />
```

Now create **`MainFragment.java`**:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Button breedButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.pokemon_breeding_button);

        breedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, new BreedingFragment());
                transaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

Include all the code before returning the view (`return v`) because it is not possible to find button and other elements of layout if the view is not exist. The `transaction.addToBackStack("tag");` helps to add the fragment into back-stack and enables to return to close the fragment with back-press.

Now create the second fragment **BreedingFragment.java`**:

```
public class BreedingFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_breeding, container, false);
    }
}
```

***Note: Import the required libraries for above classes before declaring the class.***

**Conclusion:** The app was crashing with device orientation because the second fragment was launched with button click and MainFragment was hosts by MainActivity. With the device orientation the Fragments were closed and there was no code in `MainActivity.java` to initiate the fragments again, therefore, it was giving empty exceptional error. After adding the fragment related code into `MainActivity.java` to initiate the fragment programatically solved the problem.